# Electron js not rendering react built web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, electron, electron-builder

My react web app runs fine in development mode, it also works fine when I host the build version from express server. But when I try to render it from electron js it does not render anything.

In console, it says  `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND main.8d9a4060.chunk.css:1` `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`  and I cant understand what is causing the issue.

my electron code is like this:-

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { 
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

app.on('ready', createWindow);
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Comment: How do you launch React and electron? (What is your `start` script)? Try to follow this [guide](https://medium.com/@devesu/how-to-build-a-react-based-electron-app-d0f27413f17f#:~:text="start": "concurrently \"cross-env browser=none yarn react-start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"")

Answer (score 0):

try 'loadURL' instead 'loadFile'
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window